Windows Drive Name Is Permanently Renamed?
When I plug in any external drive, the drive name keep showing as E: PANDORY, which I did rename one drive to in the past, but they used to show up as the blank name of the drive manufacturer, how do I change this to just show correct drive names as per original?

Just right click on the drive, choose the option to change the name, and delete the text. Drive name is linked to the letter associated not a physical drive.


Revert Drive Names: To show original manufacturer names instead of "E: PANDORY," right-click the drive, go to Properties, and rename it under the General tab.

Correcting Drive Names: Change the display name back to the original manufacturer's name by updating it in the drive's Properties.

Fixing Drive Labels: Adjust the drive name from "E: PANDORY" to its original manufacturer's title through the Properties menu.


